# How to convert HTML to PDF and add headers/footers

Tags: c#, .net, itext, xmlworker

I am using HTMLWorker.ParseToList() to parse the elements from a html string. But it is deprecated. What is the replacement of that function? I found that the XMLWorker is the replacement of HTMLWorker, but it doesn't contain any ParseToList() function.

**UPD**: Use case: I want to make a pdf from a Html file and also want to add a header and a footer using html files.

Comment: NO it doesn't answer my question.  On that answer, you will find a question raised by @nad. which is the same question I'm asking right now.  But that was unanswered.

Comment: Hi, any which iText version are you using? Any reason not to switch to iText 7?

Comment: @alexeySubach i don't have any specific reason to switch. I want to make a pdf from a Html file and also want to add a header and a footer using html files. so can you please tell me which can be use to implement this using itext 7 ?

Comment: See my answer on how to do that with iText 7

Answer (score 1):

pdfHTML 4.0.2 allows you to make a PDF from an HTML file and add headers and footers easily in a completely declarative style (so only using HTML+CSS combination without necessity to write a lot of boilerplate code).

And you can even add page numbers to your output PDF, all with pure CSS instructions that are processed by pdfHTML.

Here is an example of an HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
  #header {
    position: running(header);
  }

  #footer {
    position: running(footer);
  }

  @page {
    @top-center {
      content: element(header);
    }

    @bottom-center {
      content: element(footer);
    }
  }

  #current-page-placeholder::before {
    content: counter(page);
  }


  #total-pages-placeholder::before {
    content: counter(pages);
  }
</style>

<div id="header"><p style="color: green">This is a header</p></div>
<div id="footer"><p style="color: red">This is a footer. Page <span id="current-page-placeholder"></span>/<span id="total-pages-placeholder"></span></p></div>

<h2>An ordered HTML list</h2>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="A">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="I">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="i">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Visual output result:

[image: result]

And that is achieved by a single line call:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File("in.html"), new File("out.pdf"));
```

Comment: I have one file that contain the contents and have another file that contains the header and footer. I need to merge this two into one pdf file. what is the procedure to do that? I have done this by using HTMLWorker.ParseToList() then I added that list to that pdf.